# VSTS (VSO) Creating a custom dashboard widget

Tags: tfs, azure-devops

I can't find any information about creating a custom widget for VSO Dashboards. I would like to develop my own custom widget and I would like to know first of all if that is possible. If so, would you be able to give me a link or a tip that could get me started?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We are eagerly awaiting the ability to create custom dashboard widgets too, but the SDK is not available yet (as of Jan 2016).

Karen Ng blogged about this earlier in the month: [Dashboard Futures](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/visualstudioalm/archive/2016/01/11/dashboards-futures-january-2016.aspx)

> 3rd Party SDK
>
> When we launched dashboards, we mentioned that our widgets are written as extensions, allowing you to write and share your own widgets.  Widgets are implemented as a contribution point in the extension framework.  We’ll be releasing a public preview of the widget SDK in Q1 of 2016.  You’ll need some knowledge of JavaScript, HTML, CSS, and a good idea to build a widget.  Stay tuned to our features timeline to hear more.

So Q1, hopefully we'll see it in the next couple of sprints.  Stay tuned to the [Visual Studio Team Services Features Timeline](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/news/release-archive-vso.aspx)

Comment: In case anyone missed it, this has now gone into public preview: https://www.visualstudio.com/integrate/extensions/develop/add-dashboard-widget